# Automation testing of application developed using WxWidgets

Tags: automation, wxwidgets

Is there a possibility to do a automation testing of application developed using WxWidgets on windows platform? If so how do I do that?

Answer (score 4):

wxWidgets uses native widgets so any automated testing solution for Win32 programs would work with wxWidgets applications. However IME the typical "point-and-click" tests are not that great in practice and it's better to write the tests for the GUI code in the same way as you do it for the rest of the program.

There are two problems that need to be solved when doing it though: first, how to trigger various actions in the GUI. This is addressed by [wxUIActionSimulator](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_u_i_action_simulator.html). It is not perfect, but if your application has a reasonable keyboard interface (as it should), it should be enough.

The second problem is related to the control flow in the GUI applications: if some action results in opening of a modal dialog, the test can't continue until the dialog is closed by user, which is inappropriate for unattended tests. wxWidgets provides (still somewhat experimental and not documented yet) `wxTEST_DIALOG` macro for dealing with this, its use is explained in [this comment](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/master/include/wx/testing.h#L451).

Combination of these two approaches allows to write tests for the real-life GUI applications and, moreover, the tests are portable and not limited to Windows platform.